# Powershell returns access denied on non-os files used by IIS site

Tags: windows, iis, powershell, command-line-interface, file-permissions

I am connected as a local administrator using **RDP** to my **WIN2K16** server, and manage it using **gui** and **powershell**.

Overall I have full control over the machine, and never had permission errors using both methods. Yet, when running PS and CMD as an administrator I am unable to do some actions on files and directories used by my default IIS site.

I'm able to bypass this error with commands that support the `-force` flag, for example:

`Remove-Item foo` returns `access is denied`, but `Remove-Item foo -force` works fine. Removing the same files using the gui also works. However actions such as `certutil -hashfile foo MD5` will return `access is denied`, and have no gui alternative or `-force` flag.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: "Force" gives you access to Hidden and Read Only files so it's likely one or both are set. Clear both Attributes and try your `certutil` command again

Comment: Please post the output of `Get-Item -Path foo -Force | Select-Object -Property Mode, IsReadOnly, Attributes`, where `foo` is a file that causes your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by users [jfrmilner](https://serverfault.com/users/548623/jfrmilner) and [Thomas](https://serverfault.com/users/536173/thomas) in the comment section, it seems all the files located at the root directory of the default website were tagged as 'Read Only'.

I'm not sure if it is done by default by IIS (as non default sites I run also tag all their files as 'Read Only'), or it is some sort of a security policy I assigned in the past.

To conclude, disabling this attribute solved this mystery.